# ArrayIndex Error In Firestore Android Pagination

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

While Implementing the pagination in android firestore application, when the scrolling is done till end there comes an error as below

Facing this error while paginating the data in android Firestore application

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1

at line

> lastVisible = t.getResult().getDocuments().get(t.getResult().size() -
>   1);

Below is the code been implemented

```
    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    ProductModel productModel = document.toObject(ProductModel.class);
                    list.add(productModel);
                }
                productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                lastVisible = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(task.getResult().size() - 1);

                RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                        if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                            isScrolling = true;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
                        int firstVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                        int visibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                        int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();

                        if (isScrolling && (firstVisibleItemPosition + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) && !isLastItemReached) {
                            isScrolling = false;
                            Query nextQuery = productsRef.orderBy("productName", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).startAfter(lastVisible).limit(limit);
                            nextQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> t) {
                                    if (t.isSuccessful()) {
                                        for (DocumentSnapshot d : t.getResult()) {
                                            ProductModel productModel = d.toObject(ProductModel.class);
                                            list.add(productModel);
                                        }
                                        productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

//Error Line                                      
  lastVisible = t.getResult().getDocuments().get(t.getResult().size() - 1);

                                        if (t.getResult().size() < limit) {
                                            isLastItemReached = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                };
                recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear that `task.getResult().size()` is returning 0.  This error is suggesting you're getting an empty result for the last page - there are no more documents to page through.  You will need to disregard this last page.  Don't attempt to render it.

Comment: Then how should I check for the last visible document to do the pagination? I request you to advise me on some code. If I remove this **task.getResult().size()** , it is not showing any error but it is also not loading the documents further as it is supposed to happen in pagination. Please advise.

Comment: You can request one more document than you need, then check to see if that extra document exists to know if there is another page.